# Does TestCafe integrate with C# .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I need to write end to end tests in TestCafe for a system in which backend is written in C# .Net. I need to initialize data for the system under test (SUT) by accessing SUT API (WCF service or REST client) and providing the needed data. Is it possible using TestCafe?

Answer (score 2):

TestCafe performs end-to-end testing for your front-end web pages on any browser and platform for your manually coded or [automatically-recorded](https://www.devexpress.com/products/testcafestudio/) tests. It does not matter what back-end technologies are used.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few workarounds to initialize SUT with the needed data

1. use test/fixture hooks before each test/fixture. More info here: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/test-code-structure.html#initialization-and-clean-up. The drawback to this solution is that SUT must expose say Rest API that can be accessed for test init purposes
2. run a data initialization script before each test/fixture (maybe good old Selenium can be used here, or SQL script od DB directly).

As @Alex pointed out, it's not aware of backend technology that's used. Therefore no integration possibility with C# for example...